# How to delete or overwrite a secret in OpenShift?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I'm trying to create a secret on OpenShift v3.3.0 using:

```
oc create secret generic my-secret --from-file=application-cloud.properties=src/main/resources/application-cloud.properties -n my-project
```

Because I created the same secret earlier, I get this error message:

```
Error from server: secrets "my-secret" already exists
```

I looked at `oc`, `oc create` and `oc create secret` options and could not find an option to overwrite the secret when creating it.

I then tried to delete the existing secret with `oc delete`. All the commands listed below return either `No resources found` or a syntax error.

```
oc delete secrets -l my-secret -n my-project
oc delete secret -l my-secret -n my-project
oc delete secrets -l my-secret 
oc delete secret -l my-secret 
oc delete pods,secrets -l my-project
oc delete pods,secrets -l my-secret
oc delete secret generic -l my-secret
```

Do you know how to delete a secret or overwrite a secret upon creation using the OpenShift console or the command line?

Answer (score 24):

"my-secret" is the name of the secret, so you should delete it like this:

```
oc delete secret my-secret
```

Add `-n` option if you are **not using** the project where the secret was created

```
oc delete secret my-secret -n <namespace>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope **by this time you might have the answer ready**, just **sharing if this can help others**.

As on today here are the **details of CLI version and Openshift version** which I am working on:

```
$ oc version
oc v3.6.173.0.5
kubernetes v1.6.1+5115d708d7
features: Basic-Auth

Server <SERVER-URL>
openshift v3.11.0+ec8630f-265
kubernetes v1.11.0+d4cacc0
```

Let's take a **simple secret with a key-value pair generated using a file**, will get to know the **advantage if generated via a file**.

```
$ echo -n "password" | base64
cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

Will **create a secret with this value**:

```
$ cat clientSecret.yaml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: test-secret
data:
  clienttoken: cGFzc3dvcmQ=

$ oc apply -f clientSecret.yaml 
secret "test-secret" created
```

Let's **change the password and update it in the YAML file**.

```
$ echo -n "change-password" | base64
Y2hhbmdlLXBhc3N3b3Jk


$ cat clientSecret.yaml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: test-secret
data:
  clienttoken: Y2hhbmdlLXBhc3N3b3Jk
```

From the definition of `oc create` command, it **creates a resource if found throws an error**. So this command **won't fit to update a configuration of a resource**, in our case its a secret.

```
$ oc create --help
Create a resource by filename or stdin
```

**To make life easier**, Openshift has provided **`oc apply` command to apply a configuration to a resource if there is a change**. This command is **also used to create a resource**, which helps a lot during automated deployments.

```
$ oc apply --help
Apply a configuration to a resource by filename or stdin.
```

```
$ oc apply -f clientSecret.yaml 
secret "test-secret" configured
```

By the time **you check the secret in UI, a new/updated password appears on the console**.

So if you have noticed, first time apply has resulted in `created` - `secret "test-secret" created` and in subsequent `apply` results in `configured` - `secret "test-secret" configured`